# What’s the best way to handle multi section settings panel using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web-applications

I have a web app which has a settings panel, the panel has 5 section and each section has 1 to 3 tabs. It’s like:

- **Profile**: Info, Password, Phones
- **Social Media**: Facebook, Twitter, Etc.
- **Billing**: List of Transactions, Recharge, Etc.
- etc.

Right now I’ve handled this by creating a `SettingsModel` and fetching it’s data from server. I’ve made the model using `backbone-nested` plugin, so I can do something like: `birth.year` etc.  Also I’m using `Backbone.ModelBinder` to live bind the model to DOM so I don’t have to re-render with every change or set the model data manually.

Also for parts like Phone Numbers I’ve created a subview because I can’t handle those using `ModelBinder` I have to do it manually because they are nested.

My question is:
Is there a better way to handle the whole situation? Because right now I have no idea how to handle the save procedure (should it be auto or using a save button or ...). I’m willing to use stuff like Backbone Relational but I don’t know how exactly (logically).

Any sugesstions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used `backbone-nested` or `Backbone.ModelBinder` so I'm not 100% sure of the best approaches for them. Still it sounds like the best way to handle the save if when a tab changes. I'm assuming the `SettingsModel` is passed to each tab view so each view could then trigger an event (eg `save:changes`) on the model right before it closes and is removed from the DOM for a new view. In the simplest case you just need to have some listener in your model for that event to call save. If you wanted to do it in the initializer, something like

```
#CoffeeScript
initialize: ->
  @on 'save:changes', @save

//JavaScript
initialize: function() {
  this.on('save:changes', this.save);
}
```

This will send the entire model back to the server. If your model is bigger and your API can respond to PATCH requests and you want to send only the changes to the server you can make it a little more advanced.

```
#CoffeeScript
initialize: ->
  @on 'save:changes', ->
    @save @changedAttributes(), patch: true

//JavaScript
initialize: function() {
  this.on('save:changes', function() {
    this.save(this.changedAttributes(), { patch: true });
  });
}
```

Docs for [save](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) regarding `patch` and [changedAttributes](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes) (this is considered safer to use than `this.changed`).

On thing I wouldn't recommend is performing a `save` from a `change` or `change:#{attr}` event on the model since it *sounds* like `Backbone.ModelBinder` will be firing many change events depending on how it is doing data binding.

Let me know if this helps or if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks! So you suggest triggering a custom event on tab change, this is definately doable for me. Since Backbone.ModelBinder (and similar stuff) trigger many `change` events that wasn’t suitable and I see you wouldn’t recommend it either. Thank you again :-)